# how do i get subtext source code without Web platform installer?

Tags: subtext

I check all over the net and i can't find a way to get the new version of subtext without using the Web platform installer? Why do we need to install a installer in order to get the source code? what's the purpose of this additional hoop? does anyone know how to get any of the web app on the web gallery without using the web platform installer?

edit: ok, i find it on the [link text](http://code.google.com/p/subtext/downloads/list)

still what is the purpose of the web installer? why not just give us the source?

Answer (score 1):

The Web Platform Installer is used to download and install the *product* on your machine. It can handle things like applying the appropriate IIS settings, setting permissions on the file system, etc...

So it's great for getting a running instance of Subtext or other web software working on a server.

If you want the source code, go to http://code.google.com/p/subtext